# Using global resources in XAML (Application vs Page)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm basically new to the Windows Phone 8.1 development. But, I've been meaning to ask what is the difference between defining page resources and application resources?

While they seem to do the exact same thing, I guess there must be some difference between those two and that's what I would love to know. Why should I pick one over the other ?

I have a pretty simple example which could help you answer my query.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Navy"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Firebrick"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

           vs 
    <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Navy"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Firebrick"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thank you for your time ! ! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application resources are `global`, so conceptually they should contain only the resources that apply to every single page/control or any other object in the app.

Page/Control and similar resources are `local`, so they are not intended to be reused outside of those objects.

However using one versus the other has performance and other implications. In general global application resources tend to increase performance in XAML vs regular local resources (unless you are using static local resources, which perform better).

In terms of clean design, using application resources promotes tight coupling (which is not good), since your page and related resources are not self-contained.

Comment: I think I guess I understand ? So, even though it might impact the performance of the overall app, it would be better to use page resources because there is less coupling ? @TheZenCoder

Comment: Yes, that is cleaner. i would do that with any optimizations you can make (e.g. static resources).

Comment: Perfect, you were truly helpful !  Thank you @TheZenCoder